# C++ Modifying a TGA file and adding to a certain channel

Tags: c++, tga

this is what i am getting [image: this is what i am getting]
this is the image i am supposed to output
[image: this is the image i am supposed to output]I am attempting to add a number to the  green channel of a loaded TGA file, but I am getting the wrong result, also when I add zero, it returns a modified image.

Here is my code and the function i am using.

I have believe the error might be on how i am structuring the code, but other than that maybe its my code structure.

```
`#ifndef PROJECT2_TGA_READER_H
#define PROJECT2_TGA_READER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct TGA_HeaderData{
    char idLength;
    char colorMapType;
    char dataTypeCode;
    short colorMapOrigin;
    short colorMapLength;
    char colorMapDepth;
    short xOrigin;
    short yOrigin;
    short width;
    short height;
    char bitsPerPixel;
    char imageDescriptor;
};
struct Pixel_Data{
    char blue;
    char green;
    char red;
};


class TGA_Reader {
public:
    TGA_Reader(string file_name);

    TGA_HeaderData HeaderData{};

    vector<Pixel_Data> pixels;

    void DeclareFile(string file_name);

    void createFile(const char *name, const TGA_HeaderData &headerData, const vector<Pixel_Data> &pixels);

    TGA_Reader add_green_channel(int value);
};

#include "TGA_Reader.h"

TGA_Reader::TGA_Reader(string file_name) {
    DeclareFile(file_name);
}

void TGA_Reader::DeclareFile(string file_name) {
    ifstream file(file_name, ios::binary);
    if (!file){
        cout<<"not open"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.idLength, sizeof(HeaderData.idLength));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.colorMapType, sizeof(HeaderData.colorMapType));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.dataTypeCode,  sizeof(HeaderData.dataTypeCode));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.colorMapOrigin, sizeof(HeaderData.colorMapOrigin));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.colorMapLength, sizeof(HeaderData.colorMapLength));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.colorMapDepth, sizeof(HeaderData.colorMapDepth));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.xOrigin, sizeof(HeaderData.xOrigin));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.yOrigin, sizeof(HeaderData.yOrigin));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.width, sizeof(HeaderData.width));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.height, sizeof(HeaderData.height));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.bitsPerPixel, sizeof(HeaderData.bitsPerPixel));
    file.read((char*)&HeaderData.imageDescriptor, sizeof(HeaderData.imageDescriptor));

    pixels.reserve(HeaderData.width*HeaderData.height);



    for (int i = 0; i < HeaderData.width*HeaderData.height; i++) {
        Pixel_Data pixel;
        file.read((char*)&pixel.blue, sizeof(unsigned char));
        file.read((char*)&pixel.green, sizeof(unsigned char));
        file.read((char*)&pixel.red, sizeof(unsigned char));
        pixels.push_back(pixel);
        }

    file.close();
    }


void TGA_Reader::createFile(const char *name,
                            const TGA_HeaderData &headerData,
                            const vector<Pixel_Data> &pixels) {
    ofstream outfile;

    outfile.open("/Users/diegogomez/CLionProjects/Project2/cmake-build-debug/Hello3.tga",ios::binary);

    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.idLength, sizeof(headerData.idLength));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.colorMapType, sizeof(headerData.colorMapType));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.dataTypeCode,  sizeof(headerData.dataTypeCode));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.colorMapOrigin, sizeof(headerData.colorMapOrigin));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.colorMapLength, sizeof(headerData.colorMapLength));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.colorMapDepth, sizeof(headerData.colorMapDepth));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.xOrigin, sizeof(headerData.xOrigin));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.yOrigin, sizeof(headerData.yOrigin));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.width, sizeof(headerData.width));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.height, sizeof(headerData.height));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.bitsPerPixel, sizeof(headerData.bitsPerPixel));
    outfile.write((char*)&headerData.imageDescriptor, sizeof(headerData.imageDescriptor));

---


    cout<<pixels.size()<<endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.size(); i++) {
        outfile.write((char*)&pixels[i].blue, sizeof(unsigned char));
        outfile.write((char*)&pixels[i].green, sizeof(unsigned char));
        outfile.write((char*)&pixels[i].red, sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
    outfile.close();
}

TGA_Reader TGA_Reader::add_green_channel(int value) {

    TGA_Reader copy(*this); // make a copy of the object
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.pixels.size(); i++) {
        int pixel = (int) (copy.pixels[i].green + value);
        if (pixel < 0) {
            int pixel = 0;
        }
        if (pixel > 255) {
            int pixel = 255;
        }
        (unsigned char)(pixel);
        copy.pixels[i].green = pixel;

    }
    return copy; // return the modified copy}
}`
```

Comment: What do you think the line `(unsigned char)(pixel);` does?

Comment: @DrewDormann it would turn the int pixel to a char variable

Comment: What error?  What result are you expecting?  What actually happened instead?

Comment: That line does not create a "`char` variable".  That line does not create any variable and does not change the type of `pixel`.

Comment: @DrewDormann ok, do you know what might be causing the image to process differently.

Comment: @DJA15 differently from what?

Comment: @Wyck i am trying to add to the green channel of an image that is input to my class. But the output image is incorrectly modified. the brighter colors seem to come out unaltered.

Comment: What does "wrong result" look like?  What does "process differently" look like?  What does "incorrectly modified" look like?  What actually happens?

Comment: For starters, you don't have any code here that calls `add_green_channel`.

Comment: Warning: It doesn't happen all that often but nothing guarantees that `char` is 8 bits and `short` is 16 bits.

Comment: @wyck I am doing that on a different file since i believe my errors are in the classes

Answer (score 2):

This section of code is a mess:

```
        int pixel = (int) (copy.pixels[i].green + value);
        if (pixel < 0) {
            int pixel = 0;
        }
        if (pixel > 255) {
            int pixel = 255;
        }
        (unsigned char)(pixel);
        copy.pixels[i].green = pixel;
```

By doing `int pixel = 0;` you're declaring a new variable called `pixel` that is hiding the variable declared on the first line of the snippet above.  You do so again in the next `if` block.  you should drop `int` from both those lines.

Furthermore, `(unsigned char)(pixel);` is a *do-nothing* statement with no side effects.  You probably meant:

```
        int pixel = (int) (copy.pixels[i].green + value);
        if (pixel < 0) {
            pixel = 0;
        }
        if (pixel > 255) {
            pixel = 255;
        }
        copy.pixels[i].green = (unsigned char)pixel;
```

There are many more things that are poor.  Such as, you're casting to `unsigned char` when the target variable `.green` is declared as just (signed) `char`.  You should probably use a `uint8_t` for these types.

Comment: Definitely go `uint8_t`. Otherwise `copy.pixels[i].green + value`  overflows a lot sooner than you want, likely rolls over negative, and gets clipped by the `pixel < 0` test.